# Reliable stateful services / actors state reference

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, stateful-actor-service

In Azure Service Fabric I can use stateful services and actors. A state type is like a normal .net object type. So I can create multiple instances of that state.

When I am pushing an instantiated state object from one stateful service/actor to another stateful service/actor, will the state object instance be copied or just referenced? Because it is not referenced, but copied, then I have to store the state data twice. Right?

Comment: When you down vote the question, please leave a comment. That is helping me to improve my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Services span nodes in a cluster. Anything you send from one service to another has to be able to cross machine boundaries, so any object you send in a message must be serialized and sent over the wire.

Comment: That means all the data will be duplicated if I want to use them in other services/actors?

Comment: Right, if you send data from one service to another, it is a copy of the data because the services may be in different processes or even different machines. Remember, with stateful services data is co-located with the service itself - it's not stored in an external location.